# Add numbers in a list relative to a given index

Tags: python, list, indexing, addition

I'd like to know if there's a bult-in function in Python to add the elements of a list relative to a specific index. Let me explain. Say I have a list `list = [1,2,3,4,5]` . I want to be able to add the numbers of lets say `list[0:2]`. In this case the answer would be 6.

I know for a fact that I could do it with a simple loop but I would prefer a one liner, if possible.

Anyway, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `sum(your_list[0:2])`. This is easy and very fast. BTW, avoid calling your list `list` because it will shadow the built-in `list` function.

Comment: Thanks! And just out of curiosity, do you know what type it is when we do list[0:n]? Does it generate a list or a tuple containing only the elements you specified?

Comment: @Gaboik, it's a list.